# Google script fetching API with trigger but not resulting real time data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google script trigger for tracking the plugin's version from all my wp websites by fetching an API from each website, I also attach the "last update" time to see the last time the API was called.

but when my trigger runs, it keeps resulting in the same data since the first call, even when I add/delete new plugins. From the error catch, the function runs smoothly but the result doesn't there.

why is it? do google script store the data? or is there any limitation in fetching API data?

*edit*

here's the code of the function to fetch the API and the trigger function

```
function teste()
{
  var all_data = getDataFromPluginList()
  /*return
  [ { first_cell: 'A2',
    last_cell: 'I8',
    first_row: 2,
    last_row: 8,
    total_row: 7,
    url: 'https://example1.wpengine.com/' },
  { first_cell: 'A10',
    last_cell: 'I15',
    first_row: 9,
    last_row: 14,
    total_row: 6,
    url: 'https://example2.wpengine.com/' } ]

  */

  for (var i = 0; i < all_data.length; i++) {
    trigger_(all_data[i].url, all_data[i].first_row, all_data[i].last_row, all_data[i].total_row);
  }
}

function trigger_(url, first_row, last_row, total_row)
{
    var new_trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("writePluginData").timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();
    var trigger_id = new_trigger.getUniqueId();
    PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty(trigger_id, url+","+first_row+","+last_row+","+ total_row);
}

function writePluginData(event) 
{

  var trig = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  let sheet_name = 'trigger_result';
  let lowest_row = lowestRow(sheet_name);
  for(var i =0; i<trig.length; i++)
  {
   if(trig[i].getUniqueId()== event.triggerUid )
   {
    var urlParam = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty(event.triggerUid);
    urlParam = urlParam.split(",");
    var url = urlParam[0];
    var first_row = urlParam[1];
    var last_row = urlParam[2];
    var total_row = urlParam[3];
    var new_first_row = 0;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheet_name); // change accordingly
    var data = ListPlugins(url);
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      let empty = ''
      data[i].push(empty);
    }

    if(total_row != data[0][7]){
      ss.deleteRows(first_row, first_row);
      ss.getRange(lowest_row + 1 , 1,data[0][7],9).setValues(data);
    } else {
      ss.getRange(first_row, 1,total_row,9).setValues(data);
    }
   }
  }
}

function ListPlugins(url) {
  let sheet_name = 'apps and plugins'

  var options = {
     "async": true,
     "crossDomain": true,
     "method" : "GET",
     "headers" : {
       "Token" : TOKEN_HERE,
       "cache-control": "no-cache"
     }
   };
  var urlEncoded = encodeURI(url)
  let api_url = urlEncoded + "/wp-json/bd/v1/public/plugin-list/"
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api_url,options)
  var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText())

  if(object){
    return object;
  } else {
    return "not found"
  }
}
```

and the result data would be like this

[image: result data example]

Comment: What is `Google script trigger`? Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: It's impossible to help without code to look at

Comment: @Tanaike it's a trigger i made to regularly call an API and write/update my sheet data

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that `Google script trigger` was the time-driven trigger. As another question, can I ask you about the detail of `but when my trigger runs, it keeps resulting in the same data since the first call, even when I add/delete new plugins.`?

Comment: @Tanaike when my trigger run for the first time, the trigger fetch the latest data, but when trigger run again the second time, the result same as the first one. I expected it to change at least on the `last update` data

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `but when trigger run again the second time, the result same as the first one.`, in your script, `everyMinutes(1)` is used. For example, when you change this to `everyMinutes(10)`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike results arrived the same as previous, but one thing I found my triggers doing well, just not specifically updating the `last update` for `everyMinutes(1)`, instead, calling the API more or fewer hours later after the latest update of the plugin data, any idea why?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. Can I ask you about the detail of your reply?

Comment: for example, the first trigger resulting `last update` data with `2023-02-03 08:47`, but the second trigger run result is the same as the first one, the  `last update` data still `2023-02-03 08:47`, I expected to be `2023-02-03 08:48` since its a `everyMinutes(1)` trigger